# If no portion of the JOINed table is used, can it be removed?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm optimizing some code, and come up with a query like:

```
SELECT 
   t.ID
   MAX(CASE WHEN t.line=1 THEN zt.title ELSE NULL END) as primary_title
   MAX(CASE WHEN t.line=2 THEN zt.title ELSE NULL END) as sec_title
   MAX(CASE WHEN t.line=3 THEN zt.title ELSE NULL END) as tert_title
   MAX(CASE WHEN t.line=4 THEN zt.title ELSE NULL END) as quat_title
FROM table t
      LEFT JOIN btable b   on b.id=t.id
      LEFT JOIN ztable zt  on zt.id = b.id
      LEFT JOIN dtable d   on d.id = b.id  -- Is not used, yet in execution plan, table is fully accessed and scanned, causing query to run much slower. 
WHERE t.line in(1,2,3,4)
GROUP by t.id
```

If I remove that last join, I'm not effecting the results in any way correct, since no column in dtable is used?

I'm doing some testing, and haven't found any differences in the result set with or without the join, but just wanted to ask the experts.

Thanks!

Update: fixed type on dtable join.

Comment: What do you mean by "on d.b.id"? (That is invalid syntax, so you probably have a typo - but what should it be?)

Comment: Oops, yes, typo.  Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: As I explained in a Comment to Gordon's answer, the last left join may cause the result set to have duplicate rows which it would not have otherwise. For example, if the (corrected) join condition is d.id = b.id, and there are some b.id that match more than one d.id, that will cause the corresponding rows in the result to be duplicated. Nothing else will change, but you will have unnecessary duplicates in the result.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy, but since i'm only selecting t.id (grouped by), and max(...), any duplicated lines caused by the last join, wouldn't matter, correct?

Comment: Oh, right, because you group by t.id which is the same as b.id which is the same as d.id. You (and Gordon) are right in this case!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, in this case.  But for three reasons:

1. No columns from `dtable` are being referenced.
2. The joins are `LEFT JOIN`s, so they are not doing any filtering.
3. The aggregation function is `MAX()` so duplicates have no effect on the results.

Comment: That's not quite right. If there are duplicates because the join condition for the last join is satisfied more than once, then the `max()` don't change, but the result will still have duplicates that it wouldn't have otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy, but since the results are using Max() aggregate function on none of the columns in dtable, the results of the query would be the same, correct?

Comment: I would, but the OP's comment would then look out of place. I agreed with you and the OP, both here and under his question, I hope this will not confuse other readers.